# How to connect Raspberry Pi 3 and FPGA cylone IV E Altera for Uart communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, fpga, uart

I'm trying to connect Raspberry Pi 3 and FPGA for UART communication. I connected directly two pins of my FPGA to the rx and tx pins of my Raspberry Pi 3. However, the data received by Raspberry Pi is not the data sent by FPGA.
In simulation everything works fine. What is happening? Is something with the connection?

Comment: Is there a common ground?

Comment: @Joris no.. two distinct power supplies.

Comment: That might be your problem. You need a common reference for UART.

Comment: Did you receive anything on the Raspi? If so, and it’s gibberish the baud rates might not match. If you are constantly receiving some gibberish, not just at the moment when expected check the GND connections from the FPGA to Raspi - they need to be connected. Also check if you are driving the FPGA pins with LVCMOS33.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both devices have the same ground as reference. You can either achieve this by shorting the ground pins on both devices or connecting them to the same power supply.

Without a common reference, what is a high value for the FPGA might be interpreted as a low value by the Raspberry Pi because it doesn't "know" what to compare it to.